# What is meant by Class<Type> in C#?

Tags: c#

What is meant by Class in C# ? eg public interface IUser

```
public class CustomUser : IUser<string>
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

In above case what we call IUser class and why we have  in front of it?

Comment: Can you write in English please?

Comment: `IUser` is an interface not a class, and the `<string>` is the generic type parameter of the interface `IUser`

Answer (score 1):

`IUser` is a so called *generic interface*.
It's an interface that changes its definition (return types and parameters of the functions) based on the type put between the angular brackets.

More here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-type-parameters

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that `IUser` interface looks like this;

```
public interface IUser<T>
{
    void A(T a);
}
```

And the `CustomUser` class should be like this;

```
public class CustomUser : IUser<string>
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public void A(string a)
    {

    }
}
var customUser = new CustomUser();
customUser.A("Sample");
```

You tell it that `A` method parameter must be string for `CustomUser : IUser<string>`